# how to do an operation on variable in flask app

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have the following flask code:

```
def save_data(input_data):
    df = pd.DataFrame([input_data])
    df.to_csv('out.csv')

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        input_message = request.form['user_input']
        input_time = get_time()
        input_data = [input_message, input_time]
        if request.form['submit'] == 'exit':
            save_data(input_data)
            return "exit"
        else:
            return render_template('user_input.html', user_input=input_message)
    return render_template('user_input.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to run the `save_data` function every time I get new input data from the user. The code runs, but the save_data function never appears to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure save_data() is being called? The conditional ```if request.form['submit'] == 'exit' ``` will only execute the code block if the submit button value is exactly equal to 'exit'? Is that condition met?

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand a little more. I want save_data() to run after I click the exit button.  I moved the function to `if request.form['submit'] == 'exit'`, but this still doesn't work when I click the exit button

Comment: is the if conditional being met? maybe throw a print() above the save_data() call?

Comment: The condition wasn't being met as I thought. It is now and works, thanks for the tips!

Comment: boom! happy to hear it.